# Why does the database not reflect the changes made by the php INSERT?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I am calling INSERT and DELETE Statements via PHP to a MySQL Database.
The PHP script finishes successfully, but in the database nothing has changed. So I believe it must have to do with transaction handling. But I start and end the transaction. 
Does anyone has an idea? 
Thanks a lot.

```php
<?php
require_once '../extra/pdo_connect.php';
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
if (isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata)) {
    $json_obj = json_decode($postdata,true);

    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    $sql  = "delete from user where username = '?'";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $rows = $stmt->execute(array($json_obj['username']));
    $echo("Statement executed");

    $pdo->commit();
}
?>
```

As the "Statement executed" is in the Response, the DML and the transaction should have been sucessful.

Comment: For prepared statements, you don't have the single quotes round ? in `'?'"`

Comment: You're not actually checking the result of `$stmt->execute` so how can you be sure it succeeded?

Comment: The POST Request returns with Code 200. That is why I believe the PHP-Script threw no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Nigels remark was the key. 
Instead of '?' I just used ?.
After taht it worked well.

Thanks a lot for your help!!